# An exact auto-updated copy of another Confluence page

Tags: confluence

I have two separate Confluence spaces which shares some identical pages that I need to update from time to time and I want these pages to have exactly the same content in both spaces.

I see four options:

1. Maintain (update) two separate copies, in each space, totally manually.
2. Use fake pages like `Go to: [link]` in one space to link to another one.
3. Force (if possible) Confluence to [add link to second space in first space's sidebar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108127/21486).
4. Use a macro (or any other solution) that will be changed into exact copy of given page in another space and will be then somehow auto-updated.

I have tested first and second solutions and I can keep using them, if I don't find any alternatives, but they are -- of course -- not very professional ways of solving this problem.

Unfortunately, [I don't have corresponding privileges](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108127/21486) to make use of third option.

For fourth solution I need to find such macro or craft one myself and this is more like question for Stack Overflow than for this page.

But maybe there is any non-macro, "clickable" way of achieving this -- through Confluence base functionality or some "magical" configuration switch? (I don't have required privileges, but I can always try to reason my Confluence's admin to click some things for me, if such solution exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`excerpt` and `excerpt-include` macros [(manual)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Excerpt+Include+Macro) should help -- mark the master copy with  `excerpt` (all of it or just a section) and include it elsewhere as many times as you need.